# What is the equivalent of border-radius in roblox studio?

Tags: roblox, border-radius

I have been previously working with css and there is a property in that i.e., `border-radius` with which i can change the radiuses of all the four sides independently. Now i have started making roblox games and i want to round my GUI elements but i found only one plugin that is roundify which rounds all the four corners equally but i want to round them independently (seperate rounding values for different corners). I searched the property panel also but did not find that. Please can anyone tell me how to change the border-radiuses differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs for UICorner](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/UICorner).

> To use the UICorner UIComponent:
>
> 1. Create a Frame / ImageLabel / ImageButton /TextLabel /  TextButton / ViewpointFrame / etc.
> 2. Insert a UICorner component as its child
> 3. Adjust the round corner radius by changing the CornerRadius property

There are also notes about when to consider using 9-Slice image assets as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have used the plugin that you use to roundify the corners, and I looked into how it worked.

What I think is happening here is that the plugin, rather than adding a script, just changed the button to a rounded image.

You would have to find a way to make an image where all corners can be rounded separately, probably with an outside program. From what I see there isn’t really a way to do this with scripts.

Hope this helped.